# horizontal swipe is not working properly

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider

I have 5 images and i want them to be displayed inline and first when it should show 3 or 2 images and when i need next image i should be able to swipe the image to left side to see more images.

I've got a plugin and it working good except when i press the mouse button and swipe it to left it just catching the mouse behavior and without click the mouse again where the mouse pointer goes the images follows the same direction 
.

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-12">
         <div class="horizon-swiper">
           <div class="horizon-item">
              <img src="img/tabimage1.jpg">
           </div>
            <div class="horizon-item">
              <img src="img/tabimage2.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="horizon-item">
              <img src="img/tabimage3.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="horizon-item">
              <img src="img/tabimage2.jpg">
            </div>
           <div class="horizon-item">
              <img src="img/tabimage2.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Example scroll to bottom to see the images menu option [LINK](https://store.google.com/in/product/pixel_2?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI2aSk0-3n1gIVVI-PCh2v4gJGEAAYASAAEgIcF_D_BwE&dclid=CMrMjtXt59YCFYqKaAodHDwAzQ)

[Plugin Here](http://horizon-swiper.sebsauer.de/)

Comment: Hi @Tanmay have you tried this, it is a better option http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-thumbnail-scroller/

Comment: thats good but i want swipe

Comment: Please check this http://idangero.us/swiper/demos/05-slides-per-view.html

Comment: have you guys seen the google site .I want the same functionality please